# Can a program designed to use mpi be run with a gpu?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, gpu

I am executing a program with several cpu processors using mpirun. Could I run it, instead of by using the cpu, the gpu? Or should I change my code in order to archieve it?

I can work either on windows or on ubuntu and my gpu is from amd.

Comment: GPU's are specialized CPU's that have been optimized for graphic operations, similar to a DSP.  You can run code on it, but the environment (such as memory map, io ports, object code, pipelines) will be different than what you are used to.

Comment: What progress did you make when you did your own research into this matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, without re-coding.